# Control game audio and chat audio separately with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows-8, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, skype, gaming

I have Logitech G510 Keyboard with all of these extra "G-Buttons" on the side, is there a way I can put these buttons to use by controlling game/chat volume separately when pressing the buttons?

Example, lets say I am playing a multiplayer game on steam and chatting on skype with my friend, is there a way I can press G10/G9 for up/down volume for skype only, and G8/G7 for up/down volume for steam games only? That way I can put the chat volume down when I need to hear the game louder, or lower game volume and put chat volume up, without having to exit any app!

Any help or direction to the right way would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First you need to find the Scancode of those keys, which we can use to create Hotkeys using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). One easy way is to find scan codes is [scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21105-crazy-scripting-scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key/).